# Either did not add the component to your page at all, or that the hierarchy does not match in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

Currently i m working one requirement in wicket framework.i done some coding part related to that.but i got hierarchy does not match expection always.i followed the hierarchy,but do not wt wrong i did.

```
here is my requirement:

by clicking on tab,i would like to display progress bar.i used ajax lazy load concept here..

Here is code:
ConditionalListView<Ancillary> orderAncillariesNavigationList = new ConditionalListView<Ancillary>(
        "ancillaryItems", orderAncillaryList) {
        @Override
      protected void populateItem(ListItem<Ancillary> item) {
        final Ancillary ancillary = item.getModelObject();
        // add ajax link
       final AjaxLink<String> navigationLink = new AjaxLink<String>("ancillaryLink") {

          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

          @Override
          public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // replace data with this ancillary
            replaceWithSelectedAncillary(target, ancillary);
            target.appendJavascript(CLEAR_BIG_EASY_FEEDBACK);
          }
       };
        navigationLink.add(new Label("ancillaryLinkName", ancillary.getLabel()));

        //progress bar

        if(ancillary.getLabel().equals("Episode / Show Descriptions")){
            add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("lazy")
            {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String id)
                {
                    // sleep for 5 seconds to show the behavior
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    return navigationLink;
                }

            });
          }

       // set class
        if (ancillary.getId().longValue() == selectedAncillary.getId().longValue()) {
          item.add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>("selected"), " "));
        }

        item.add(navigationLink);
        //item.add(TestPage());

      }
    };

HTML:

<div class="reset">&nbsp;</div>  
      <div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
      <div wicket:id="lazy"></div>
       <div id="ancillaryNavigation">
       <ul id="ancillaryTabs" class="group">
        <li wicket:id="ancillaryItems">
       <a href="javascript://" wicket:id="ancillaryLink"><span wicket:id="ancillaryLinkName">Music Cue Sheets</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>  <!--  /#ancillaryTabs -->
      </div>  <!--  /#ancillaryNavigation -->
      <form wicket:id="ancillaryManualForm" name="ancillaryManualForm" class="epForm"> 
        <div wicket:id="ancillaryOrderEpisodes" />
      </form>
    </div>  <!--  /#ancillaryOrders -->

Please help me out.What i did wrong here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to the wicket examples for adding links to the list view. Here is my observation from your code: 1. You are loading a link in lazy load. Is the loading of your link going to take long time or the panel being loaded on click of the link is going to take long time?  2.you don't add label to the link as child component,  you can set the label of the link via property model. 3. Check the sequence of your markup components and java components structures. Parent -child components hierarchy must match.

I would first start with taking small steps one at a time;  looking into wicket examples for all the different components I am using.

Comment: Hi Mihir,Thanks for ur responce.Actually my requirement is in panel we have 3 tabs,one of my tab loading time is 30 sec.So i unable to shown any thing to user while it processing or not.so here i implemented lazy load for that particular tab.